# How do I add Ubuntu to the msconfig boot menu on windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu to a separate partition, with the GRUB bootloader on that partition.

I am now wondering how to add the GRUB bootloader to msconfig in windows 7 so it will ask me to boot to Ubuntu or win 7, upon booting my windows 7 bootloader. I would add it to the boot.ini except that windows 7 doesn't have it, everything is managed through msconfig.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had install Ubuntu on a separate partition, then use Easy BCD to add an entry to the windows boot loader, that points to Ubuntu's GRUB boot loader on the other partition.

Comment: What does Easy BCD do in terms of commands? I don't want to pay $35 USD for a product I know little about.(I do use my computer for commercial purposes)

Answer (score 0):

Install from within Windows.
Wubi and the Live iso in a folder.
Run wubi and boot live.
Do install.
Entry is added to Windows database of boot options.
From within Windows (as admin) use command prompt and bcdedit /?
Bcdedit /enum to list entries

Comment: Wubi is creating a file inside your windows instead of a seperate partition. Thats not really what he wants. He has already installed ubuntu ;)

Answer (score 0):

In msconfig You have to change the time of other systems displaying at boot time.
When You turn on computer does it show GRUB or just goes to Win7 instantly?